# Minidom: How can I check if I have the expected root and children?

Tags: python, xml, minidom

I have this xml structure,

```
<root>

    <child1>
    </child1>
    <child2>
    </child2>
    <child3 />
    <extendedchild:name>
    </extendedchild:name>

</root>
```

How can I check with minidom, that root is `root`, and that children are always the followin elements?

```
child1
child2
child3
extendedchild
```

I want also to print the elements that are out of root or not in the above "children list"(**outofroot, notachild**):
...

```
    <notachild />
</root>
<outofroot />
```

**Edit**:
It seems that `outofroot` element is treated by the `minidom` parser, it gives `xxxxxxx.xml has an error: junk after document element: line 12, column 0`

Comment: It seems that `outofroot` element is treated by the parser, it gives `xxxxxxx.xml has an error: junk after document element: line 12, column 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use minidom to walk though the children and verify that the name of the root node is `"root"`. You can then process children one at a time and verify the other requirements.

```
if not root.tagName == "root":
   # do something
for node in root.childNodes:
   # do something more
```

If necessary, you can process the child nodes recursively.

```
def processChild(node):
    # do some checks on node
    for child in node.childNodes:
        processChild(child)
```

Comment: `root=`?, `root=documentElement`?

Comment: Yes, `root=doc.documentElement`

Answer (score 1):

As far as the root element name check, looks like you can do it like this:

```
import xml.dom.minidom
dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlString)
if dom.documentElement.tagName == "root" ...
```

You should be able to for..in iterate on the root's `.childNodes`.

If something is outside of the root, it is not a well-formed XML document (which can only have one root node).

Comment: It seem that `outofroot` is treated by the parser, it gives `xxxxxxx.xml has an error: junk after document element: line 12, column 0`

Comment: `root=`?, `root=documentElement`?

Comment: As far as outofroot, it is treated by the fact that it is not allowed. :) yes, it should be `documentElement` if it behaves like normal DOM.